# How add custom validation to my razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, client-side

I have razor page in my mvc 4 application .Now imagine i have a simple textbox in my page as follows :

```
@Html.TextBox("Email")
```

or

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" />
```

how can I do some client-side validation for this field you know something like asp.net web forms validation controls . I want to make it required and write a Regex for it .

Comment: There are already validation options for your specific example. Use the strongly-typed helpers + data attributes.

Comment: @TiesonT.- Could you be more specific plz

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336030.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I use to do this:

- In the model Person.cs :

  ```
      [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener mas de 50 caracteres")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
      public string Nombre { get; set; }
  ```
- In the page Create.cshtml:

  ```
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Person.Nombre" class="control-label">Nombre / Name:</label>
          <input asp-for="Person.Nombre" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="Person.Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You generally decorate your model properties with the `RequiredAttribute` and the `RegexAttribute`.

Comment: But I don't pass a model into my razor page Its just a simple log in form !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Data Annotations. They provide very simple and straightforward way for you to define your (not only) validation for every field in every view model.

Please take a look at the following link:

[How to: Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In your particular case, it will be

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"<your RegEx>", ErrorMessage = "<your message, leave out for default>")]
public string fieldYouValidating { get; set; }
```

Other way for validation preferrable by many is [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

```
RuleFor(x => x.fieldYouValidating)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("This is the message.");
```

Hope this helps